# Pass variable from jenkinsfile to docker-compose as environment variable

Tags: docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to set environment variable to docker-compose from Jenkinsfile. Next command - launch docker-compose

My docker-compose file now looking like this:

```
services:
  myService:
    image: someImage:latest-release
    environment:
     - SOME_ENV=${FOLDER_PATH}
```

For some cases I tried - I left only name of var, without value. In order to set value later.

I tried many options. Tried export and launching docker-compose with env var in the beginning, like: `SOME_ENV=VALUE docker-compose...`
Last one - using `.env` file. And then launch script from Jenkinsfile:

```
sh '''#!/bin/bash
set -exuo pipefail
FOLDER_PATH="$(realpath ./my/path/to/folder/)"
echo SOME_ENV=$FOLDER_PATH >> Docker/.env
"$(docker-compose -f Docker/ci.docker-compose.yml up -d --build)"
```

But I would like something like this, at least as close as possible, if it possible:
In jenkinsfile:

```
def dcl = "docker-compose -f Docker/ci.docker-compose.yml"
def VIDEO_PATH = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "realpath ./automation/reports/selenoid/video/")
sh "SOME_ENV=$VIDEO_PATH $dcl up -d --build"

But as I see - because of few shells I cannot do it...

I need find some way how is properly set var from Jenkinsfile as env var to docker-compose
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I spent almost a day trying to resolve it. Args, environment in compose, combining with separate container with arg, env in it... Only one thing helped me - creating env_file in compose (not .env) in run-time and setting my env variable in it. May be .env file could also helped in case of windows, not sure, in my case (linux) not